# Difference between DbContextTransaction.Commit() and context.Database.CommitTransaction()

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ado.net

What is the main differences between two commit types?

```
            bool adresVarmi = false;
            using (var trans = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
            {
                adresVarmi = dbContext.MUSTERI_ADRES.Where(x => x.MUSTERI_TANIM_ID == dto.MusteriId).AsNoTracking().Count() > 0;
                trans.Commit();
                dbContext.Database.CommitTransaction();
            }
```

Is it same for high traffic applications?

Comment: Side point: `AsNoTracking().Count()` why would you do this? That means you have to pull all the data back from the server, then count it up. And why do `Count > 0` when you can use `.Any()`. So you could simplify this to `adresVarmi  = dbContext.MUSTERI_ADRES.Any(x => x.MUSTERI_TANIM_ID == dto.MusteriId);` And obviously a single statement doesn't need an explicit transaction anyway. If you are just doing this to use `ReadUncommitted`, think again: `ReadUncommitted` has *serious* data integrity implications. It is unnecessary in the vast majority of cases, ....

Comment: .... because if you have concurrent writers, you will get incorrect results, and `Snapshot` would be a better isolation level. If you have no concurrent writers you could just lock the whole table with a table-lock, it won;t affect anyone if there are no writers

Comment: @Charlieface I did it for performance issues. Almost my every select query has isolation level for getting data. I have e-commerce application. So I did it for.
Is it wrong for getting data. I just want nolock.

Comment: I presume you are also aware then that it can return *completely* incorrect results, including but not limited to: reading rows or even whole pages twice or not at all, reading data that fails unique or foreign key constraints, or even check constraints, rows which are meant to be unique causing joins to double up, can cause "data has moved" errors, can still block DDL such as index maintenance, and so on. It's the wrong solution for almost any problem involving locks. As I said, you should probably use `IsolationLevel.Snapshot` in most cases.

Comment: See also these articles https://sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/08/but-nolock-is-okay-when-the-data-isnt-changing-right/ and https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/quaere-verum-clustered-index-scans-part-iii and this one from an actual Microsoft employee https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/281562/220697

Comment: I used readonly only user related data. Not shared data. For ie customer's basket, orders etc. So only changer is customer. Still is wrong to read with uncommited?

Comment: Yes, what happens when a page gets split, or an index gets rebuilt? The pages will move about and you will end up reading a load of rows twice. The fact that the *rows* you are dealing with are not being directly changed doesn't mean that nothing else will change them. What problem are you trying to solve? If it's performance then you definitely shouldn't be doing this, the gain is miniscule, the loss substantial. Or do you have locking problems? You could use a `ROWLOCK` hint to avoid most locking problems, if you are dealing with a small amount of rows. For reporting queries use `Snapshot`.

Comment: My app is e-commerce. I used EF on it. Evertime customer's basket rebuild (delete and insert). Other queries arent important because they are product queries like select product infos etc. My team leader direct me for use nolock almost every select query. So since I used EF, I planned to use Isolationlevel for nolock.

Comment: There may be exceptional cases where it is necessary and you have been through all of the implications, every single query is *certainly* overkill. You may cite those articles (and others) to him. Coming from a team leader I would expect better. It's very bad practice and I will say no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
context.Database.CommitTransaction()
```

is equivalent to

```cs
context.Database.CurrentTransaction.Commit()
```

The main purpose for that method is to be able to commit the current transaction from code which did not call `BeginTransaction()` or has no access to the returned `IDbContextTransaction` object. It will fail if there is no current active transaction.

Since you are the one who starts the transaction and have access to the returned `IDbContextTransaction` object, it is preferable to issue `Commit()` on it rather than using `CommitTransaction()` method.

i.e. the following is preferred (note that you shouldn't call both as in your example since the second will fail because there won't be active transaction after the `Commit()` call):

```cs
using (var trans = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    // do something...
    trans.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. For question I added two commit codes. Actually in web applications there is no differences I understand. But safe way is IDbContextTransaction commit method with named instance. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned at the end.